# How can I see the response of the request while recording a performance test in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, performance-testing

How can we see the response of the request when recording a web performance test in Visual Studio 2013.

I am able to see the response tab and its details when a recorded run happens though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is shown in the web browser used to record the test. The browser has assorted debugging tools accessed via the F12 key. The browser context (right-click) menu also offers "view source" on many pages.

After a test has been recorded and run, clicking the "Recorded Result" icon in the "Test Results Viewer" will display the requests and responses etc from when the test was recorded. These recordings are the "xxx.webtest.{guid}" files saved in the folders of the solution.